Karhunen–Loève theorem proof
I was looking at Karhunen–Loève theorem on Wikipedia.
It consider a square-integrable random process $X_t$ indexed over the closed interval $[a,b]$. In the proof an orthonormal basis is taken in $L^2([a,b])$.
What is exactly the space $L^2([a,b])$ ? Is it the space of square-integrable functions over the closed interval $[a,b]$ ?
I'm confused about the difference between $L^2(\Omega,F,P)$ vs $L^2([a,b])$ both involved in the theorem's proof.

By convention $L^{2}([a,b])$ is $L^2(\Omega,F,P)$ where, $\Omega =[a,b], F$ is the Borel $\sigma-$  algebra and $P$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$.

Btw, in the definition of measurable function (as in this case of the square of function $f$ in $L^2([a,b])$) it is always assumed that the range of the real-valued function ($f^2$ in this case) has the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on the reals, right ?
